# Contniuty in $\mathbb{C}$ of a function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C},D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$

It used to be a Question but now I think I have solved the Problem now.

I have sometimes confused the terms preimage and preimageset

> Show that a function is continious in a point $z_0$ in $D$ if and only
>   if the preimages of neighbourhoods of $f(z_0)$ are neighbourhoods of
>   $z_0$ in $D$ and a function is continious if and only if the preimage
>   of every  open subset in $ \mathbb{C}$ is open in $  D$

Suppose $f$ is continious in $z_0$  if $|x-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$ than it is necessary that $f^-1(x)$ is in a delta environment of $z_0$ otherwise it has no preimage.

Now the other side

LoveTooNap29 suggests to consider an arbitrary epsillon neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$, the preimage is again a neighbourhood of $z_0$ by assumption, neighbourhood of $z_0$ means that the Elements do not leave $D$ AND there exists a $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the distance between $z_0$ and any Point of the preimageset is smaller than $r$ which is equivalent to the existince of a deltaenvironment where all the preimages of the Elements in the neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ sits in. Therefor picking a delta smaller or equal than $r$ and bigger then $0$ yields Images in lessthan-Epsilon distance of $f(z_0)$. Which is the Definition of continiuty written out.

But what is with the other Statement?

My Idea is to prove the first implication of the second Statement with a constructive Argument. f is continious and now I pick a open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that means two Things I cannot pick $\mathbb{C}$ itself because then the corresponding immageset would be the whole set $f(D)$ which is never open. (I can also not pick a subset which contains $f(D)$). Also if I pick a subset where no Images of $f$ are within then the corresponding preimageset would also be empty and thus always open again by Definition. I am therefor picking a set which does not fall under those categories.

Because the set I have picked is open it means that it is a neighbourhood of every Point. That means it is a neighbourhood for every Point which has a preimage in $D$. Then applying what I have proved above and the fact that union of open sets are open again proves that the preimage of the open subset in $\mathbb{C}$ we have chosen is also open in $D$.

Now assuming the other side : The preimage of every open subset in $\mathbb{C}$ is also open $D$. What I Need to Show is that f is continious in every point.

Assuming there exists a point $z_0$ in $D$ where $f$ is not continious then there exists a neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ which is a open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that the preimageset $P$ is not a neighbourhood of $z_0$ (with preimageset I mean  the set of all Elements in the neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ which have a preimage). No neighbourhood means in this case that $\forall_{r\in\mathbb{R}}\exists_{p_r \in P}|z_0-p|\geq r$. Now $z_0\in P$ is always true because a neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ is a set which always contains $f(z_0)$. Since $P$ is not a neighbourhood of $z_0$, it cannot be open. This is a contradiction to the assumption.

$\square$

Comment: What definition of continuity are you working with?

Comment: f is continious in z 0  

 then for all ϵ>0 

 there exists a δ>0 

 such that |z−z 0 |<ϵ⇒|f(z)−f(z 0 )|<ϵ

Comment: Pick an arbitrary neighborhood of $f(z_0)$. Consider it's pre-image. What do you notice?

Comment: Hint: This is true for arbitrary metric spaces. There's nothing special about $\mathbb{C}$.